# What are the zeros of $z^6-5z^4+z^3-2z \in \mathbb{C}$ within the unit circle?

Tags: complex-analysis, polynomials, roots

Obviously $z=0$ gives a zero. 
However now I'm stuck because it is not so easy to solve a fifth degree polynomial equation. 
Is there maybe a trick from complex analysis we can apply?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By Rouché's theorem, your polynomial has as many zeros within the unit circle (counting with multiplicity) as the polynomial $-5z^4$. That is, it has four zeros.

Comment: Why $-5z^4$ ?...

Comment: Beacuse, when $|z|=1$, $|-5z^4|=5$, whereas $|z^6+z^3-2z|\leqslant4<5$.

Comment: That is quite a theorem

Comment: I fully agree. It looks like magic.